# Why is hashing the info dict turning out wrong?

Tags: java, bittorrent, bencoding

I have been trying for ages to get this hashing thing for BitTorrent to work in Java but it always becomes wrong.

I have narrowed it down to a few lines of code where I'm 99% sure the problem is:

```
Bencode bencode = new Bencode(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[33237];
Map<String, Object> dict = bencode.decode(fileBytes, Type.DICTIONARY);
Map infoMap = (Map) object.get("info");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BencodeOutputStream bos = new BencodeOutputStream(baos);
bos.writeDictionary(infoMap);
byte[] hash = DigestUtils.sha1(baos.toByteArray());
```

I have hardcoded the size of the array just to make sure the issue is not caused by a bunch of zeroes hanging around.

I have tried with both `UTF-8` and `US-ASCII`.

I have tried using two different libraries for the bencoding so it's probably not there where the problem's at.

**Edit:** From the spec it seems that the info dict should be urlencoded as the info_hash. So I tried writing out the dictionary into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then do the sha1 hashing on the `byte[]` that `ByteArrayOutPutStream` is holding.

Will the `DigestUtils.sha1`method provide a URL encoder? Can't find any information on that.

Comment: When in doubt, debug

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing, but I looked up [the spec](https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification). Is it the `info_hash` you're trying to calculate? It says that should be the value of `info`, not of `pieces`

Comment: @thatotherguy It seems that way when reading it, yes. Hasn't worked when I tried though. In your opinion would you assume the info map is already sha1 encoded? Seems that way from reading it but it's all quite vague at the same time.

Comment: The info map is bencoded: "urlencoded 20-byte SHA1 hash of the value of the info key from the Metainfo file. Note that the value will be a bencoded dictionary". How do I run your example? You don't provide any input or output data

Comment: Thanks. It seems that my code now is decoding the big dictionary, grabbing the decoded info dictionary, encoding it and then doing the sha1 hashing. Doesn't that seem like a reasonable flow to get it working?

Comment: Save the string: `d4:infod6:lengthi1e4:name5:a.txt12:piece lengthi32768e6:pieces20:1234567890abcdefghijee` as *mini.txt* * Rename to *mini.torrent* * You have now created a bogus but valid torrent with the info_hash: `831F79C1C8358FCEB75496C3A81E113EA8147F13` * Add a line in you code that instead of hashing, prints the string * Run code and compare with above values

Comment: A normal info dict contains binary data, so UTF-8 or ASCII won't do. It must be a type that can handle binary strings. The info_hash should only be URL encoded when sent to a tracker as a HTTP-get announce, NOT when the info_hash is calculated.

Comment: @Encombe Thanks a lot for the replies! I created that file and used the above code except for changing the hash type to a `String` and it printed the correct hash. So, as you say, there must be something wrong with the encoding. Because now the file can be encoded in _UTF-8_ but when it has special symbols that's not possible. But how can I possibly do this with a binary string when the library requires an encoding?

Comment: Tried it with both the libraries now that I have been using for _bencoding_. The simple example works with both but once I try a real file it's no longer working. The second library only uses _UTF-8_. Should I first try and convert the `byte[]` from the file to _UTF-8_ and then send it to the library or is there any standard _charset_ available that can handle this?

Comment: Also tried removing everything except for the info dict in a torrent file and hashing it directly without bencoding but it is still not working.

Comment: The value for the obligatory *pieces* key in the *info* dict will contain binary data, so it's a must that the code can handle that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The torrent info\_hash parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191480/the-torrent-info-hash-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as Encombe pointed out, was with the encoding. In the Bencode specification it talks about *byte strings* and this seems to point to it just being a stream of data without any encoding.

Both of the libraries I looked at converted all byte strings to some encoding so I wrote a Bencode library that only did the conversion when specifically asked to.

The code above is basically correct but here is the client code I am using now:

```
public void readManifest() throws IOException, Exception {
    byte[] fileBytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes);
    BDecoder decoder = new BDecoder(bis, "UTF-8");
    BDict dict = decoder.decodeDict();
    Map<String, Object> valueMap = dict.getValue();
    infoMap = (Map<String, Object>) valueMap.get("info");
}

public String hash() throws Exception {
    if (hash == null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BEncoder encoder = new BEncoder(baos, "UTF-8");
        encoder.encodeDict(infoMap);
        hash = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(baos.toByteArray());
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Good. You can verify that it can handle the [special case of a unsorted info-dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749085/calculating-the-info-hash-of-a-torrent-file/19800109#comment44844341_19800109) by saving `d4:infod4:name5:b.txt6:lengthi1e12:piece lengthi32768e6:pieces20:1234567890abcdefghijee` as *unsort_dict.torrent* It should have the info_hash: `34FCC6C1ACC8C8A56DE3C2EF20924043CC51685E`

Comment: @Encombe I receive that hash, yes. I'm using a LinkedHashMap so everything is ordered the same way as it is read.

Comment: Small note: While it is 100% correct that bencoded "strings" actually are arbitrary byte sequences (BEP52 clarifies this) one can use ISO 8859-1 as workaround to treat them as string because it 1:1 maps raw bytes to unicode codepoints (i.e. `char` values in java). But this is a hack because those `String` instances will contain garbled data if it was actually supposed to be UTF8. But still a useful hack if one has to pass around byte data through APIs that expect strings.